# PHP reformat JSON output

Tags: php, arrays, json, construct-2

I'm building a hi score board in construct2 and am trying to lay out the chars correctly.

In order to do this I have created an array in c2 and am using AJAX to return data as a JSON string from a php script held on my webserver. This data will then be used to populate the array which I will then use to fill out my SpriteFonts. Simple enough in theory.

This is the php file that returns the JSON string:

```
if ($result = $mysqli->query($sql))  {
    /* fetch associative array */
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $array = array(
        array
        (
            'name' =>  $row['pName'],
            'score' => $row['score']
        ));     
        echo json_encode($array);
    }

    /* free result set */
    $result->free();
    exit();
}
```

This returns the following:

```
[{"name":"developer","score":"56"}]
[{"name":"Terrry","score":"34"}]
[{"name":"Numero_Uno","score":"20"}]
[{"name":"Thomasin :)","score":"18"}]
[{"name":"ThriftyButStillNifty","score":"18"}]
[{"name":"Perfect","score":"17"}]
[{"name":"bah","score":"17"}]
[{"name":"EvilEdna","score":"16"}]
[{"name":"type here","score":"16"}]
[{"name":"Slaine","score":"14"}]
```

To be used in C2 the string needs to be in this format:

```
{"c2array":true,
"size":
    [2,2,1],
"data":
[
[["John"],[23]],
[["Terry"],[43]]
]
}
```

How do I go about creating one from t'other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do something like this:

```
$response = array(
    "c2array" => true,
    "size" => "something",
    "data" => array()
);

while ( $row = $result->fetch_assoc() ) {
    $response['data'][] = array(
        array($row['pName']),
        array($row['score'])
    );
}

echo json_encode($response);
```

Comment: Ye, thats perfect with the slight addition of `$foo = array(10,2,1);` to cater the size section of the response. TVM.